# Add variables to flask session in multiple routes

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating an application where variables are assigned in multiple routes. Each route can add the variables to sessions when they are on their own, but when I try to assign in both routes, sessions only updates the variables from the second route.

I originally was using global variables instead of sessions and the program ran correctly. It also worked correctly when sessions was only updated in one route. I thought the problem may be due to returning 
    '', 204 
but the problem persisted when I switched the JavaScript that called '/form' to ajax and returned jsonify.

When sessions is updated in both routes, I get a KeyError.

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['POST'])
def handle_form():
    session['collegeName'] = request.form.get('selector')
    print("/form " + "College Name: " + session['collegeName'])

    for row in collegeData:
        if row[0] == session['collegeName']:
            session['collegeInfo'] = row
    print("/form " + "College Info:", session['collegeInfo'])
    session.modified = True

    return '', 204

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    tempdir = mkdtemp()
    fileList = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for key, f in request.files.items():
            if key.startswith('file'):
                filepath = os.path.join(tempdir, f.filename)
                f.save(filepath)
                print(filepath)
                print(readFile(filepath))
                fileList[escape(f.filename)] = readFile(filepath)
        session['fileList'] = fileList
    else:
        fileList = {}
    rmtree(tempdir)
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/completed')
def completed():

    print(session['fileList'])

    fileList = {}
    for fileName in session['fileList']:
        fileList[fileName] = highlight(session['fileList'][fileName])
    return render_template('results.html', fileList=fileList, title=session['collegeName'])
```

`session['collegeName']` and `session['collegeInfo']` do not update, but `session['fileList']` does.

The print statements in '/form' also print the correct output.The highlight function in '/complete' does not run because `highlight()` uses `session['collegeInfo']`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. `completed` does not use `session['collegeInfo']`. And what does "sessions only updates the last variables" mean?

Comment: Completed uses `highlight()`, which just iterates through `session['collegeInfo']`. When I  add the variables to session in both routes, it only updates the variable from the second route. In this case, it only updates `session['fileList']`.

Comment: since you have only given code snippet, i have to ask.  are you doing `from flask import session` and have you set SECRET_KEY?  not doing these two things would make `session` an ordinary variable in terms of scope and life.  check [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#sessions)

Comment: I've done both of those things.